# Total return time series for an interest rate swap

Tags: interest-rate-swap, index

Without paying for a bespoke dataset or tool, how can I go about creating a total return time series for irs eg for 10y sofr swap such that it includes spot price move + carry/roll?

I’m doing this so that I can generate cta trend following signals on the total return time series of IRS across tenors and currencies

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to BBG? Search for U.S. Bellwether Swaps Index. Total return indices are available from 3m to 30 years. These are legacy Lehman/Barclays indices and they continue to be calculated. An old reference paper is available at https://www.pm-research.com/content/iijfixinc/12/2/28.

If you want to calculate this yourself, you'd assume that you enter into a par swap at the end of each month/quarter, then simply mark-to-market this swap on a daily basis using updated swap curves to compute the daily P&L.

Given that you're trying to generate a CTA trend following strategy, I wonder whether using IRS is the way to go. It might be easier to work with bond futures.